# Secure way resetting forgotten XMPP / Jabber password

Tags: passwords, xmpp, reset, forgot-password

I'm maintaining a XMPP / Jabber Server using [prosody](https://prosody.im/) (nightly build).
The registration module is activated and user are allow to create new accounts via the xmpp registration.

A user contacted me about how she*he could reset the forgotten password. The problem how to identify the user. (It is no problem to reset the password via prosodyctl).

**Ideas:**

- check the users roster / contacts and she*he has to verify 1-2. (But what if the roster is empty ?)
- add an email in your profile but it's not obligatory (At this point not sure how read the added email)

I would like to write a script / tool for the webbrowser to allow the user to reset the password, but how to verify and with which information ?

Is there any standard for this or some experience ?

Comment: The de-facto standard is email. If you don't collect these, jabber.org also operated on multiple questions: https://www.jabber.org/faq.html#password

Comment: Thanks! There are some downsides. The email in the profile vcard is public to everyone (in your roster). Last login IP is a bit hard to get for everyone or like change mobile phone IP or switching exist nodes like in university networks. I'm still not statisfied with this solution.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you take this info from the vcard. For example in Prosody set `additional_registration_fields = { "email" }` to collect this at registration time. But overall your question is a bit vague - are you asking for a solution to your current problem, or an ideal solution? My "email" response was in answer to your "with which information?" and "is there any standard?". If you don't have email addresses, or any other info, obviously you cannot safely reset the password.

Comment: Thanks! But is not really working. At the client gajim now email is available form field while register but not obligatory; but looking at the client gajim it is not. I'm searching a bit of both: A way that works for me and the ideal solution to evalutae. I agree using email is a good way, but I don't see a good, reliable way to collect it.

Comment: I think this is quite a high-level discussion and not related to programming, so too off-topic for StackOverflow - maybe join us in the Prosody chatroom for a discussion some time: https://prosody.im/discuss